# How to check if two objects contain the same words regardless of order?

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, boolean-operations

So I have two objects, names1 and names2 and they're just an array of names that the user chooses to input. I want to create a code that checks if the two objects contain the same words, regardless of the order. Like

```
Enter names ( n to stop):
John
Charles
n

Enter names (n to stop):
Charles
John

true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`List.containsAll(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-) like,

```
public boolean sameCoins(Name n) {
    return name.size() == n.name.size() && name.containsAll(n.name);
}
```

Also, your constructor currently has a raw-type (don't use raw-types). And program to the `List` interface.

```
private List<String> name;

public Name() {
    name = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Converting the lists to strings and comparing the strings is not a great approach. You can get into hot water if the names contain spaces, commas, or brackets. It's best to keep the strings distinct and work with them as is.

Whenever you want to store a bunch of items and the order of the items doesn't matter you should think "set" instead of "list". Sets are collections like lists, but sets don't preserve order.

```
Set<String> names;
```

What's great is that you don't need your `Name` class at all. A `Set<String>` does exactly what you're trying to do with your custom `Name` class without you having to write any code at all. You can add names to a set and you can compare sets with `equals()` all out of the box.

```
public static boolean sameCoins(Set<String> n1, Set<String> n2) {
    return n1.equals(n2);
}
```

The most common concrete `Set` implementation is `HashSet`:

```
Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();
```

A hash set is fast and efficient, but it has one notable drawback: it doesn't store the elements in order. If you print out the elements in a hash set they'll look sort of random. They're not the order you inserted them like a list, nor are they in alphabetical order. If that matters you can switch to a `LinkedHashSet` (preserves insertion order) or a `TreeSet` (sorts the items).